# Javascript button onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I'm trying to put my onclick handler like the following.

```
function handleFetch(cardList) {

let getList = cardList;
    
    if(getList && typeof getList === "string") {
        getList = JSON.parse(getList);
    }

    console.log("getList", getList);
    if(cardList && cardList.length > 0) {
        // if(getList.length > 0) {
            cardListOut.innerHTML = getList.map((list, index) => {
                return(
                    `<div id=id_index_${list.cardNumber}>
                        <div class=style_cardNumber>
                            ${list.cardNumber}
                        </div>
                        <div class=style_cvv>
                            ${list.cvv}
                        </div>
                        <div class=style_expiry>
                            ${list.expiryDate}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button type=button onclick=${handleRemoveCard(list.cardNumber)}>
                                Remove
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                );
            });
        // }
    }
}

function handleSubmit(event) {

    console.log(event.target.id);
    let isValidated = true;
    if(cardNumberValue === '' || cvvValue === '' || expiryDateVal === '')
        isValidated = false;

    if(isValidated) {
        handleStorage();
        // handleFetch();
    }
    else {
        invalidFields.innerHTML = "Fill up the fields correctly!";
    }
}

const handleRemoveCard = (cardNumber) => {
    cardNumber.preventDefault();
    console.log("remove", cardNumber);
    let getList = localStorage.getItem('cardList');
    let getIndex = null;
    if(getList) {
        getList = JSON.parse(getList);
        if(getList.length > 0) {
            getList.map((item, index) => {
                if(item.cardNumber === cardNumber) {
                    getIndex = index;
                }
            })

            if(getIndex !== null) {
                getList.splice(getIndex, 1);
            }

            handleFetch(getList);
        }
    }

}

my html code looks like this:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Payment Gateway Form</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="handleWindowOnload()">
        <form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
                <div>
                    <button id="buttonId" type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit(event)">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="cardListOut">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

I'm getting the error **Maximum call stack size exceeded** in the end after getting the data from the browser's **local storage** as shown in the screen
[image]
What I understood is its happening because of the default execution of the function **handleRemoveCard**. I tried applying **event.preventDefault** which is again giving me an error like **event is not defined** as I can't pass the event from the map right away like that.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the function `handleSubmit`? you haven't included this in the question

Comment: @Sean yes, added just now. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is *calling* `handleRemoveCard()` immediately. The line makes very little sense, and is causing an infinite recursive call:

```
<button type=button onclick=${handleRemoveCard(list.cardNumber)}>
```

It looks like this is what you were trying to do:

```
<button type=button onclick="handleRemoveCard(${list.cardNumber})">
```

This will work assuming that `list.cardNumber` is actually a number and not something like a string or other value.

I would strongly advise that you attach events to your elements after they are created instead of using using attributes. This is what's known as "unobtrusive JavaScript".

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve. But at the same time I'm returning the button for the particular object through map and showing on the page. now attaching the onclick separately would be another option but if there's a way which can be mentioned please specify..